# Bundle to add attribute to another entity

Tags: symfony, configuration, bundle, symfony-2.7

Hi,

I have an entity A :

- id
- att1
- att2

Now, I'd like to add a new Bundle (which will add new functionality) and here especially I'd like to add an attribute to A. A must be like :

- id
- att1
- att2
- newAtt3
- newAtt4

In order to do that, I was thinking to create a new entity which will extend A and add the new attribute.

But then, what I don't know is how can I prepare the first bundle to use the 2nd entity (and controller/view) if the 2nd bundle is installed?

I guess I need to add configuration in the first bundle, but I have no idea what to add...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Best Practices for Reusable Bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html)

and [Doctrine Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

You can also think about [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) but often the best way is to use Interfaces. With the help of interfaces you can make your bundle highly configurable on a clean way like this:

make a configuration variabele that tells the bundle what class should be used. This can be the default class A from the Bundle but may also be class A from your AppBundle.

```
    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('a_entity')
                ->defaultValue('AppBundle\\Entity\\A')
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ;
```

Then make a interface for class A with all the functions that are mandatory:

```
interface AInterface
{
    public function setVariable($name, $var);
    public function getHtml($template);
}
```

and implement the interface in the class:

```
class A implements AInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

Every time if you pass the class as a paramter use AInterface instead of A:

```
class B
{
    private $a;

    public function __construct(AInterface $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}
```

Right now you can change the configuration variabele a_entity to another class. This other class still needs to implement the interface AInterface.